# How to count peaks on chart in LabVIEW above some specific value. How to count amount of hills (Heart Rate Monitor)

Tags: labview

I want to create some simple heart rate monitor in LabVIEW.

I have sensor which gives me heart workflow (upper graph): [Waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dZdk.jpg)

On second graph (lower graph) is amount of hills (0 - valley, 1 - hill) and that hills are heart beats (that is voltage waveform). From this I want to get amount of those hills, then multiply this number by 6 and I'll get heart rate per minute.

Measuring card I use: NI USB-6009.

Any idea how to do that?

I can sent a VI file if anyone will be able to help me.

Comment: Why would you multiply by 6? Is your horizontal axis time in seconds? And what do you mean by "amount of those hills"?

Comment: Yes,horizontal axis is time. Sorry for misunderstanding, I forgot to add that program is in 10s loop so on graph we have 10s waveform of heart beat. I want to get the number of hills, precisely moment when amplitude value changes from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Threshold Peak Detector` VI

> This VI does not identify the locations or the amplitudes of peaks
> with great accuracy, but the VI does give an idea of where and how
> often a signal crosses above a certain threshold value.

You could also use `Waveform Peak Detection` VI

> The Waveform Peak Detection VI operates like the array-based Peak
> Detector VI. The difference is that this VI's input is a waveform data
> type, and the VI has error cluster input and output terminals.
> Locations displays the output array of the peaks or valleys, which is
> still in terms of the indices of the input waveform. For example, if
> one element of Locations is 100, that means that there is a peak or
> valley located at index 100 in the data array of the input waveform.
> Figure 6 shows you a method for determining the times at which peaks
> or valleys occur.

NI have a great tutorial that should answer all your questions, it can be found [here](https://www.ni.com/en-ie/support/documentation/supplemental/06/peak-detection-using-labview-and-measurement-studio.html):

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I can't check solution now because I don't have access to PC with LabView (I use it in my university), I just try to find some ways to solve this and then test all of them. When I check that I give you feedback is it work!

Comment: No problem, you could always get the four week trial if you wanted to check it out.....

Answer (score 1):

I had some fun recreating some of your exercise here. I simulated a squarewave. In my sample of the square wave, I know how many samples I have and the sampling frequency. As a result, I calculate how much time my data sample represents. I then count the number of positive edges in the sample. I do some division to calculate beats/second and multiplication for beats/minute. The sampling frequency, Fs, and number of samples, N or #s are required to calculate your beats per minute metric. Their uses are shown below.

[The contrived VI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0cly.png)

Does that lead you to a solution for your application?

Comment: Your solution will be very helpful so thank you so much for this. I'll give you feedback when I try to solve my problem again because now I don't have access to PC with LABVIEW (I use PC on university).